# Cron not creating logs

Tags: cron

This is my first time trying to create a cron job.  My server keeps getting warnings of high cpu usage so I am trying to create a cron to save a file of all processes every 10 minutes. I have created the folder already and chmod -R 777 that folder. the path is correct.  i would appreciate any help. in terminal i typed

`crontab -e`
then i typed in

```
*/10 * * * * ps aux > /var/www/html/cron/psOutput-`date +%F_%T`.txt
```

then i saved it.   if i go back and look at my cron, that line is there, its the only line.  i am lost. please help

Comment: instead of voting to close, instead you should share your insite of why my question should not be posted here.  we are supposed to be helping each other...

Answer (score 1):

You can see log of your cron job using heroku ...

$ heroku logs --ps cron.1

you will be able to see cron log...try it out.

best luck